# Sand Tefilin Hasisa

Tags: halacha, tefilin, hair, chatzitzah

If someone, let's say, went to the beach (at night of course) and got sand in his hair and it stayed in his hair, the next morning would it be considered a Hasisa (obstacle) for Tefilin?

Comment: "at night of course"? But +1.

Comment: @msh210 during the day there is most likely Perisut.

Comment: @HachamGabriel At least there isn't sakanat nefashot.

Comment: @DoubleAA Perisut isn't Sakanot Nefashot?

Comment: Depends on the situation. But please never swim at a beach at night!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Chatzitzah and must be cleaned. See [Shulchan Aruch Horav 27](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/5/27/index.htm):7 ("וה״ה בתפילין של ראש צריך ליזהר בדבר שלא יהא שום דבר חוצץ בין תפילין לשערו ועפר או כנה מתה נקרא חציצה").

Comment: What if the person is a dust salesman?

Comment: Next question: if one has a Hasisa must he don Tefilin again to be Yose?

Comment: I don't see why not.